GridGain upgrade is failing with BaselineTopology of joining node is not compatible with BaselineTopology in the cluster
Environments used: OpenShift
Existing image: gridgain/community:8.8.37-openjdk17-slim
New image: gridgain/community:8.9.5-openjdk17-slim
Both environments GirdGain cluster (3 nodes) is running with persistence enabled.
Tried upgrading the GridGain Community Edition version from 8.8.37 to 8.9.5 by scaling down the GirdGain cluster to zero.
Two of the GirdGain nodes were terminated and the third one was in terminating state for more than 30 mins (may be due to terminationGracePeriodSeconds which was set to high). Terminated that pod forcefully.
Executed the kubectl command to create the cluster with the updated gridgain version. One pod got created with the new gridgain image.  Second node fails to start with the below exception and gets restarted in a loop.
Caused by:

Terminated the pods and cleared the GridGain storage volumes.
Tried the cluster again and received the same error.
How do I perform the gridgain upgrade without losing the persisted data?

If the GridGain cluster is run via StateFull set and the pod management policy is set to Parallel (to get more information please follow the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#parallel-pod-management), there might be a scenario when the old pod hasn't completely stopped but the new one has already started. In this case, the new pod starts with an empty work directory in the same storage with the empty baseline history, because the previous pod hasn't released the lock yet. As a result, such an error may occur when the other old pods are trying to connect to this empty node.
Also, you can consider the Enterprise Edition which has a rolling upgrade feature (more information at the link https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/rolling-upgrades). It allows nodes with different GridGain versions to coexist in a cluster while you roll out a new version.
